# Show most viewed item from database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show most viewed page but didn't work as expected and showing different results. In database table there is row called `hits` and every page refresh increment `hits+1`. Now I'm trying to show on page top 5 viewed pages. Also this query show 4 images(pages) instead of 5?

```
SELECT *, count(hits)
FROM images     
GROUP BY hits
ORDER BY hits DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Table is `images` and `hits` is the row that count views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what you are asking, but my best guess is that you are making the query to complicated. Doesn't

```
SELECT *
FROM images     
ORDER BY hits DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Accomplish what you want?

This assumes TABLE Images include a COLUMN hits and that by "page" you mean image or "row in the images table associated with the page."

Comment: Well .. yes. This is what I've trying to accomplish. Thank's!